# Can I use Outlook.com to email a group BCC by default?

Tags: privacy, outlook.com, contacts-group

I created an email group in Outlook.com's webmail service. When I email the group, I have to remember each time to switch to BCC to avoid disclosing the group email addresses.

I want to know how to email the group BCC (blind carbon copy) by default. Is this possible?